# Android Grid layout is not working as expected

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a grid layout in my android application. but it displays different in some other device.

code is given below.

**Listing page ;-**

```
<include layout="@layout/action_bar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="200dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="24dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabBtnUploadFile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:tint="@color/White"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/appThemeColor"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**Listing item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pdfIcon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pdf"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pdfIcon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/geometria_bold"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textCapCharacters|textCapWords"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="name of item"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pdfIcon" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Images for display outcome.

**correct result image**
[image]

**Wrong display for same**

[image]

Can anyone suggest where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I recommend using a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager instead.

Comment: @TorkelVelure as per your advice i changed to recycler view. that worked for me.  https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example  thank you very much for your help